# (Angular)Js - how to simplify promise result?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I come from an embedded C background, and am self-taught in AngularJs 1.x; I suspect that my question is a generic JS question, rather than AngularJs specific.

I find this sort of pattern repeating in my code:

```
                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
                    {
                       console.log('Success');
                    });

               })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {
                    console.error('Error !');
                });
```

Being a C guy, I am not similar with lambdas, although I am comfortable with callbacks.

The code for the success and failure parts can be very large, and it makes the code seem messy - especially seeing all that code passed as a parameter.

I am guessing that the parameters to `$http` is/are (a) promise(s).

Is there some way that I can make the code more modular, and easier to read & maintain?

For instance, I imagine that I could declare some success/failure functions & invoke those, stemming like:

```
function it_succded(data, status, headers, config))
{
    console.log('Success');
});

function it_failed(data, status, headers, config)
{
    console.error('Error !');
});

$http.get(url)
.success(function(data, status, headers, config)
 {
     it_succded(data, status, headers, config))
   });
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config)
 {
    it_failed(data, status, headers, config)
  });
});
```

Of course, I could just code it & see, but ask here because I want to learn, and hope for an explanation from someone who truly understands this, preferably someone who codes (Angular)Js professionally.

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http; the $http methods *return* promises, the parameter there is a string. I don't know what the success and failure methods are, promises have then and catch. The parameters to those are callback functions, and yes you can extract them (but `function(args) { callback(args); }` doesn't achieve anything other than swallowing any return value; just pass `callback`).

Comment: The .success syntax was correct up to Angular v1.4.3. See the old docs here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/docs/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using the promise interface, you should not use `.success()` or `.error()`: they are [deprecated](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/). Instead, use `.then()` and `catch()`. The parameters these callbacks receive are slightly different:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
     console.log("Success", response.data);
}).catch(function(response) {
     console.log("Error", response.status);
});
```

`response` is an object that has the expected [properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns):

- `data` – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- `status` – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
- `headers` – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
- `config` – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- `statusText` – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.
- `xhrStatus` – `{string}` – Status of the XMLHttpRequest (complete, error, timeout or abort).

You could indeed define the callback functions separately, and then your callback arguments can just be function references:

```
function it_succded(response) {
     console.log("Success", response.data);
}
function it_failed(response) {
     console.log("HTTP Error", response.status, response.statusText);
}
$http.get(url).then(it_succded).catch(it_failed);
```

You could define these functions as methods, e.g. on the `$scope` object:

```
$scope.it_succded = function (response) {
     console.log("Success", response.data);
     $scope.data = response.data;
}
$scope.it_failed = function (response) {
     console.log("HTTP Error", response.status, response.statusText);
}
$http.get(url).then($scope.it_succded).catch($scope.it_failed);
```

Little note: Be aware that `this` will not be set when these callbacks are called by the Promise implementation. So either do not use `this` in them, or define them as arrow functions (`this` will then be whatever it is in the lexical context), bind the functions to a specific `this` object, or provide little wrapper callbacks:

```
.then(function(response) { 
     return $scope.it_succded(response);
})
```

Comment: Looks like I guessed correctly, but it great to have it confirmed by such a high rep user. Thanks. I will leave this open fr 24 hours to attract other answers, to help other n00bs like me, then award the answer

Comment: I don't suppose you could update your answer to declare `it_succded` and `it_failed` as `$scope` functions?

Comment: Your question is really a generic JS question (simplifying promise callbacks), so tying it even more with AngularJS concepts seems not right?

Comment: Except that I am trying to get it to work with Angular 1.x, where the function declaration syntax is different from JS :-/

Comment: The only thing that may not be supported in Angular 1 is destructuring (we're at version 7 now), so then don't do `function ({data, status})`, but `function (response)`. and address the properties like `response.data`, ...etc. I updated my answer to use that syntax.

Comment: Plus also the`$scope` example :-) Thanks. I have previously been using v1.2.5 and reckon it's about time to upgrade, so thanks for that too. Also the hint to not use `this` - which I have never done; I fail to see the point of it in AngularJs

Comment: How could I pass parameters to those response functions?

Comment: There are several possibilities, depending on your actual case. For instance, `bind` may be used. Be aware that the Promise implementation will call the function with one extra parameter (the response). If you have a particular question about this, and you cannot find the answer, consider posting a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I searched and found an answer explaining how to use `bind`, which worked just fine

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

```
$http({
your configs
})
.then(funtion(result){ // function on success
   return result.data // this is important as AngularJS $http will bind the data from the server into this variable
},
function(errorResponse){
if(errorResponse.status === 401){
    // your code for handling 401 errors
}
else if(errorResponse.status === 404){
    // your code for handling 404 errors
}
else if(errorResponse.status === 500){
    // your code for handling 500 errors
}
})
.then(function(data){
    // another function to process data
    return data
})
.then(function(data){
    // yet another function to process data
    return data
})
```

We can combine as many then callback, as we want.
you can read more about promised from this link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

Hope it will help you.